# Autofilling Form Date and Time in Chrome with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, datejs

I'm trying to populate a form on a site with values passed through GET. The two fields I'm having trouble with are input tags that are of type `type="date"` or `type="time"`. Chrome has this nice feature that gives you a drop down calendar to select a date:

[image: Chrome's Drop Down Calendar for Date Inputs]

Chrome also does something similar for the Time field. The problem is that it doesn't like javascript that tries to populate those types of form fields. I pass GET information like so:

[image: Passed Information through GET to Populate the Form Fields]

The reason the date is formatted like this is because that's what the back-end requires (not what I'm working on) and the date comes directly from the back end code.

I have a function that auto-populates `document.$_GET` as an array with all passed values from GET. I also have [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) included, which allows me to use the `Date.parse` functionality and some other stuff. I pass it through javascript like this:

```
if(document.$_GET['time']!=undefined)
  document.getElementById('time').value=document.$_GET['time']; 

if(document.$_GET['date']!=undefined){
  var date = new Date();
  date = Date.parse(document.$_GET['date']);
  alert(date.toString('MM-dd-yyyy')); // <-- Debugging
  document.getElementById('date').value = date.toString('MM-dd-yyyy'); //WHY WON'T YOU WORK!?
}
```

On Safari I get what I expect to get:

[image: Autofilled form in Safari]

With Chrome I'm left with empty form fields:

[image: Empty fields in Chrome]

I'm stumped and not sure how to remedy this. I need Chrome to autofill similar to how Safari does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome is strict about the format of the Date.

The date works with the following format, YYYY-MM-DD.
The time works with military time. (24h clock)

Here's a sample,
http://jsfiddle.net/vFnxw/2/

```
$("#date").attr({
    value:"2012-09-28"
})
$("#time").attr({
    value:"23:59:59"
})
```

Here are the sources

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.time.html

Comment: Awesome! That got the date working. What about the time? I'm guessing it's something very similar. Maybe putting a space between the time and the 'AM' or 'PM' substring? -- Nope. Not just a missing space. It's something else.